# Resolve AnonymousUser in Django

Tags: python, django, email, gmail, contacts

I have some problems when i create send email form using Django.
the problem is when i cliked for send button in contact form. I see this problem.[image]

settings.py script here:

```
"""
Django settings for Connecting_System project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-ix)p!+kk@f=47&2$%!7w98uflur_!n9o!tr77x3=r=4^r6b%bh'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'login.apps.LoginConfig',
    'Home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'logout.apps.LogoutConfig',
    'signup.apps.SignupConfig',
    'contact.apps.ContactConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Connecting_System.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join( BASE_DIR , 'templates' )],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Connecting_System.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOSTS_USER = '<youremail>@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOSTS_EMAIL = '<youremail>@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

views.py script here:

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
#from Home import templates
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def contact(request):
    # CONTACT FORM
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')

        form_data = {
            'email':email,
            'title':title,
            'subject':subject,
        }
        message = '''
        New Message: {}

        From: {}
        '''.format(form_data['title'], form_data['email'])
        send_mail(form_data['title'], message, '', ['<youremail>@gmail.com'], )
        return HTTPResponse('Thank you for submitting the form ...')

        
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

When I go to my google account to give access to my app for using my account from here [google less secure](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)
I see This setting is no longer available.

Comment: The link says, "This setting is not available for accounts with 2-Step Verification enabled. Such accounts require an application-specific password for less secure apps access." it is available, you probably have 2-factor auth enabled on your email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple spelling mistake.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<youremail>@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

Host, not *hosts*, no plural here.

It gets rejected because the config is wrong.

It couldn't find an `EMAIL_HOST_USER` ->

Tries to connect to google with `webmaster@localhost`, as seen above ->

Obviously google rejects it.

> Note
>
> Gmail does not allow you to just send emails from any server. You have to allow it.
>
> Have a look at the following tutorial if you run into any more issues: https://dev.to/abderrahmanemustapha/how-to-send-email-with-django-and-gmail-in-production-the-right-way-24ab